# How to handle multiple share mining requests in solo

Tags: solo-mining

I was testing mining algorithm for solo and noticed that server keep sending the shares to work on (semetimes every 1 sec). In case of solo mining do I need to keep mining all the existing shares I received or only take the the latest one and discard previous ?

Comment: What coin are you mining? What hardware/software are you using? What hash rate? It makes a huge difference.

Comment: Bitcoin. My question is not on luck factor. Its about what's expected for client when it keep receiving multiple requests while its still working on previous request.

Comment: It really depends on the specifics of your hardware. How long does it take to finish a work unit? How much of a penalty is there for stopping a work unit in progress (if you can)? And so on. It's a complex tradeoff.

Comment: With most modern miners, it's not an issue. They finish a work unit so fast it's a non issue.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand you correctly in order to solve a block one has to finish solving all the shares received and submit to server/node before anyone else   even for solo mining. Is that correct ?

Comment: No. Mining is only a race in the very rare case that two people mine a block at almost exactly the same time.